# AWS Cloud watch X-ray Traces shows Duration is 1000+ seconds for a API request for a AWS Lambda function, what does this mean?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

For an API call, AWS X-ray Traces shows 1000+ seconds in Duration column, but the response time is less than a second (631 milliseconds), does the 1000+ seconds Duration indicates an issue in API?

[image]

Segments Timeline Durations are around couple of seconds only

[image]

Thanks in advance for any pointers

analyzing AWS could watch X-ray Traces for API